# How to render Google Pay button in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-pay

I want to install a Google Pay button into my Google Apps Script and have it work [similar to this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fw5t6caL/).

[Here is the documentation.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#code.gs_1)

But when I use the following code, I don't see any payment button.

What am I doing wrong?

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script async
      src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js"
      onload="onGooglePayLoaded()">
    </script> 
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs

```
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#code.gs_1
// Use this code for Google Docs, Slides, Forms, or Sheets.
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .createMenu('Buy report')
    .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
    .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile( 'Index' );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog( html, 'Dialog title' );
    // .showSidebar( html, );
}

// ref: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/demos
// demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fw5t6caL/

/**
 * Define the version of the Google Pay API referenced when creating your
 * configuration
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequest|apiVersion in PaymentDataRequest}
 */
const baseRequest = {
  apiVersion: 2,
  apiVersionMinor: 0
};

/**
 * Card networks supported by your site and your gateway
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters|CardParameters}
 * @todo confirm card networks supported by your site and gateway
 */
const allowedCardNetworks = ["AMEX", "DISCOVER", "INTERAC", "JCB", "MASTERCARD", "VISA"];

/**
 * Card authentication methods supported by your site and your gateway
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters|CardParameters}
 * @todo confirm your processor supports Android device tokens for your
 * supported card networks
 */
const allowedCardAuthMethods = ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"];

/**
 * Identify your gateway and your site's gateway merchant identifier
 *
 * The Google Pay API response will return an encrypted payment method capable
 * of being charged by a supported gateway after payer authorization
 *
 * @todo check with your gateway on the parameters to pass
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#gateway|PaymentMethodTokenizationSpecification}
 */
const tokenizationSpecification = {
  type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
  parameters: {
    'gateway': 'example',
    'gatewayMerchantId': 'exampleGatewayMerchantId'
  }
};

/**
 * Describe your site's support for the CARD payment method and its required
 * fields
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters|CardParameters}
 */
const baseCardPaymentMethod = {
  type: 'CARD',
  parameters: {
    allowedAuthMethods: allowedCardAuthMethods,
    allowedCardNetworks: allowedCardNetworks
  }
};

/**
 * Describe your site's support for the CARD payment method including optional
 * fields
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters|CardParameters}
 */
const cardPaymentMethod = Object.assign(
  {},
  baseCardPaymentMethod,
  {
    tokenizationSpecification: tokenizationSpecification
  }
);

/**
 * An initialized google.payments.api.PaymentsClient object or null if not yet set
 *
 * @see {@link getGooglePaymentsClient}
 */
let paymentsClient = null;

/**
 * Configure your site's support for payment methods supported by the Google Pay
 * API.
 *
 * Each member of allowedPaymentMethods should contain only the required fields,
 * allowing reuse of this base request when determining a viewer's ability
 * to pay and later requesting a supported payment method
 *
 * @returns {object} Google Pay API version, payment methods supported by the site
 */
function getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest() {
  return Object.assign(
      {},
      baseRequest,
      {
        allowedPaymentMethods: [baseCardPaymentMethod]
      }
  );
}

/**
 * Configure support for the Google Pay API
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequest|PaymentDataRequest}
 * @returns {object} PaymentDataRequest fields
 */
function getGooglePaymentDataRequest() {
  const paymentDataRequest = Object.assign({}, baseRequest);
  paymentDataRequest.allowedPaymentMethods = [cardPaymentMethod];
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();
  paymentDataRequest.merchantInfo = {
    // @todo a merchant ID is available for a production environment after approval by Google
    // See {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/test-and-deploy/integration-checklist|Integration checklist}
    // merchantId: '01234567890123456789',
    merchantName: 'Example Merchant'
  };
  return paymentDataRequest;
}

/**
 * Return an active PaymentsClient or initialize
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#PaymentsClient|PaymentsClient constructor}
 * @returns {google.payments.api.PaymentsClient} Google Pay API client
 */
function getGooglePaymentsClient() {
  if ( paymentsClient === null ) {
    paymentsClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({environment: 'TEST'});
  }
  return paymentsClient;
}

/**
 * Initialize Google PaymentsClient after Google-hosted JavaScript has loaded
 *
 * Display a Google Pay payment button after confirmation of the viewer's
 * ability to pay.
 */
function onGooglePayLoaded() {
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest())
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.result) {
          addGooglePayButton();
          // @todo prefetch payment data to improve performance after confirming site functionality
          // prefetchGooglePaymentData();
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // show error in developer console for debugging
        console.error(err);
      });
}

/**
 * Add a Google Pay purchase button alongside an existing checkout button
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#ButtonOptions|Button options}
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/brand-guidelines|Google Pay brand guidelines}
 */
function addGooglePayButton() {
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  const button =
      paymentsClient.createButton({onClick: onGooglePaymentButtonClicked});
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
}

/**
 * Provide Google Pay API with a payment amount, currency, and amount status
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#TransactionInfo|TransactionInfo}
 * @returns {object} transaction info, suitable for use as transactionInfo property of PaymentDataRequest
 */
function getGoogleTransactionInfo() {
  return {
    countryCode: 'US',
    currencyCode: 'USD',
    totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
    // set to cart total
    totalPrice: '1.00'
  };
}

/**
 * Prefetch payment data to improve performance
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#prefetchPaymentData|prefetchPaymentData()}
 */
function prefetchGooglePaymentData() {
  const paymentDataRequest = getGooglePaymentDataRequest();
  // transactionInfo must be set but does not affect cache
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = {
    totalPriceStatus: 'NOT_CURRENTLY_KNOWN',
    currencyCode: 'USD'
  };
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.prefetchPaymentData(paymentDataRequest);
}

/**
 * Show Google Pay payment sheet when Google Pay payment button is clicked
 */
function onGooglePaymentButtonClicked() {
  const paymentDataRequest = getGooglePaymentDataRequest();
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();

  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest)
      .then(function(paymentData) {
        // handle the response
        processPayment(paymentData);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // show error in developer console for debugging
        console.error(err);
      });
}

/**
 * Process payment data returned by the Google Pay API
 *
 * @param {object} paymentData response from Google Pay API after user approves payment
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/response-objects#PaymentData|PaymentData object reference}
 */
function processPayment(paymentData) {
  // show returned data in developer console for debugging
    console.log(paymentData);
  // @todo pass payment token to your gateway to process payment
  paymentToken = paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token;
}
```

Comment: I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? By this modification, I could confirm that the Google Pay button is shown in the opened dialog. But I cannot test to pay. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that when your script is the actual tested script, the Javascript is required to be included in the HTML side. So how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script async
      src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js"
      onload="onGooglePayLoaded()">
    </script> 
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>

<script>
// ref: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/demos
// demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fw5t6caL/

/**
 * Define the version of the Google Pay API referenced when creating your
 * configuration
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequest|apiVersion in PaymentDataRequest}
 */
const baseRequest = {
  apiVersion: 2,
  apiVersionMinor: 0
};

/**
 * Card networks supported by your site and your gateway
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters|CardParameters}
 * @todo confirm card networks supported by your site and gateway
 */
const allowedCardNetworks = ["AMEX", "DISCOVER", "INTERAC", "JCB", "MASTERCARD", "VISA"];

/**
 * Card authentication methods supported by your site and your gateway
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters|CardParameters}
 * @todo confirm your processor supports Android device tokens for your
 * supported card networks
 */
const allowedCardAuthMethods = ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"];

/**
 * Identify your gateway and your site's gateway merchant identifier
 *
 * The Google Pay API response will return an encrypted payment method capable
 * of being charged by a supported gateway after payer authorization
 *
 * @todo check with your gateway on the parameters to pass
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#gateway|PaymentMethodTokenizationSpecification}
 */
const tokenizationSpecification = {
  type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
  parameters: {
    'gateway': 'example',
    'gatewayMerchantId': 'exampleGatewayMerchantId'
  }
};

/**
 * Describe your site's support for the CARD payment method and its required
 * fields
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters|CardParameters}
 */
const baseCardPaymentMethod = {
  type: 'CARD',
  parameters: {
    allowedAuthMethods: allowedCardAuthMethods,
    allowedCardNetworks: allowedCardNetworks
  }
};

/**
 * Describe your site's support for the CARD payment method including optional
 * fields
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters|CardParameters}
 */
const cardPaymentMethod = Object.assign(
  {},
  baseCardPaymentMethod,
  {
    tokenizationSpecification: tokenizationSpecification
  }
);

/**
 * An initialized google.payments.api.PaymentsClient object or null if not yet set
 *
 * @see {@link getGooglePaymentsClient}
 */
let paymentsClient = null;

/**
 * Configure your site's support for payment methods supported by the Google Pay
 * API.
 *
 * Each member of allowedPaymentMethods should contain only the required fields,
 * allowing reuse of this base request when determining a viewer's ability
 * to pay and later requesting a supported payment method
 *
 * @returns {object} Google Pay API version, payment methods supported by the site
 */
function getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest() {
  return Object.assign(
      {},
      baseRequest,
      {
        allowedPaymentMethods: [baseCardPaymentMethod]
      }
  );
}

/**
 * Configure support for the Google Pay API
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequest|PaymentDataRequest}
 * @returns {object} PaymentDataRequest fields
 */
function getGooglePaymentDataRequest() {
  const paymentDataRequest = Object.assign({}, baseRequest);
  paymentDataRequest.allowedPaymentMethods = [cardPaymentMethod];
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();
  paymentDataRequest.merchantInfo = {
    // @todo a merchant ID is available for a production environment after approval by Google
    // See {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/test-and-deploy/integration-checklist|Integration checklist}
    // merchantId: '01234567890123456789',
    merchantName: 'Example Merchant'
  };
  return paymentDataRequest;
}

/**
 * Return an active PaymentsClient or initialize
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#PaymentsClient|PaymentsClient constructor}
 * @returns {google.payments.api.PaymentsClient} Google Pay API client
 */
function getGooglePaymentsClient() {
  if ( paymentsClient === null ) {
    paymentsClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({environment: 'TEST'});
  }
  return paymentsClient;
}

/**
 * Initialize Google PaymentsClient after Google-hosted JavaScript has loaded
 *
 * Display a Google Pay payment button after confirmation of the viewer's
 * ability to pay.
 */
function onGooglePayLoaded() {
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest())
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.result) {
          addGooglePayButton();
          // @todo prefetch payment data to improve performance after confirming site functionality
          // prefetchGooglePaymentData();
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // show error in developer console for debugging
        console.error(err);
      });
}

/**
 * Add a Google Pay purchase button alongside an existing checkout button
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#ButtonOptions|Button options}
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/brand-guidelines|Google Pay brand guidelines}
 */
function addGooglePayButton() {
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  const button =
      paymentsClient.createButton({onClick: onGooglePaymentButtonClicked});
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
}

/**
 * Provide Google Pay API with a payment amount, currency, and amount status
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#TransactionInfo|TransactionInfo}
 * @returns {object} transaction info, suitable for use as transactionInfo property of PaymentDataRequest
 */
function getGoogleTransactionInfo() {
  return {
    countryCode: 'US',
    currencyCode: 'USD',
    totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
    // set to cart total
    totalPrice: '1.00'
  };
}

/**
 * Prefetch payment data to improve performance
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#prefetchPaymentData|prefetchPaymentData()}
 */
function prefetchGooglePaymentData() {
  const paymentDataRequest = getGooglePaymentDataRequest();
  // transactionInfo must be set but does not affect cache
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = {
    totalPriceStatus: 'NOT_CURRENTLY_KNOWN',
    currencyCode: 'USD'
  };
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.prefetchPaymentData(paymentDataRequest);
}

/**
 * Show Google Pay payment sheet when Google Pay payment button is clicked
 */
function onGooglePaymentButtonClicked() {
  const paymentDataRequest = getGooglePaymentDataRequest();
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();

  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest)
      .then(function(paymentData) {
        // handle the response
        processPayment(paymentData);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // show error in developer console for debugging
        console.error(err);
      });
}

/**
 * Process payment data returned by the Google Pay API
 *
 * @param {object} paymentData response from Google Pay API after user approves payment
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/response-objects#PaymentData|PaymentData object reference}
 */
function processPayment(paymentData) {
  // show returned data in developer console for debugging
    console.log(paymentData);
  // @todo pass payment token to your gateway to process payment
  paymentToken = paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token;
}
</script>
</html>
```

`Code.gs`

```
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#code.gs_1
// Use this code for Google Docs, Slides, Forms, or Sheets.
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .createMenu('Buy report')
    .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
    .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile( 'Index' );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog( html, 'Dialog title' );
    // .showSidebar( html, );
}
```